# Displaying values from multiple JavaScript slider values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get multiple sliders to display their values to the right hand side, based on an example I found: http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/

(I then want to store each slider output as a JavaScript variable to use as an input to several functions, but first thing's first.)

I added an input id and name to each of the sliders (from http://html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php) as well as a form name and id (http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/getelementbyid-form.phtml) ... but I can't seem to modify the example function ( which uses document.getElementById("range").innerHTML ) to get the value to display for one of the sliders.

Thus, in their present state, all slider values reflect the 1st slider's position as opposed to the other ones. I've tried playing around with for a while, but have not made much progress beyond adding possible identifiers that I can't grab :-p.

Can anyone explain how I can target display slider values by their name or input id instead of input type? Or point me to a resource that could show me how to modify what I have now?

That way I could have each slider display a value for its own position.

I have the sliders in my header. Code is pasted below (I've left it so that the code runs, but each number displays the first slider's position):

```
<p>   
<form name = "weight1" id = "weight1" >
<!-- http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/ -->
    <text><b> weight1 </b></text> <input id="weight1" input type="range" name="weight1" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(weight1.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    }
    </script>
</form>

<form name = "weight2" id = "weight2" >
    <text><b> weight2 </b></text> <input id="weight2" input type="range" name="weight2" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(weight2.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
</form>

<form name = "weight3" id = "weight3" >
    <text><b> weight3 </b></text> <input id="weight3" input type="range" name="weight3" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
</form>

<form name = "weight4" id = "weight4" >
    <text><b> weight4 </b></text> <input id="weight4" input type="range" name="weight4" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
</form>

<form name = "weight5" id = "weight5" >
    <text><b> weight5 </b></text> <input id="weight5" input type="range" name="weight5" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
</form>

<form name = "weight6" id = "weight6" >
    <text><b> weight6 </b></text> <input id="weight6" input type="range" name="weight6" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
</form>
</p>
```

(note: I abandoned renaming the showValue(this.value) when I realized it didn't work as a unique identifier...)

Presumably, once I know how to grab a JavaScript slider value to display, I can use that same sort of technique to assign it to a variable to use it in the body of my HTML document...

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id's have to be unique in a whole document. In this case range id is used in multiple span element. http://jsbin.com/ISekuSiN/5/